# How to view a full HTTP POST Request with J2ME

Tags: java, http, post, java-me

I'm attempting to upload an image to a server using an HTTP Post Request.  I'm running into some problems, and I'm trying to debug.  What's the best way in Java (j2me) to view the full POST request in whole? I've tried using a packet sniffer (wireshark), but I was unable to interpret the data.  Here is the code that I am using to generate/send the POST:

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).